# node-gyp is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: node.js, node-gyp

I'm trying to create C++ addon for Node.js.

I was following [this](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) tutorial and got stuck on using `node-gyp configure` command.
As I understood from [here](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp#how-to-use), I should create `binding.gyp` file and run `node-gyp configure` from this directory but I get "node-gyp is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file" error.

Node-gyp was installed using `npm install -g node-gyp`.

This must be something easy, but I'm new to Node.js and have no idea what is wrong.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve: http://luismreis.github.io/node-bindings-guide/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: do a `npm bin -g` to see where your global libraries are listed and then see if directory contains `node-gyp` (even faster if on linux `ls -l $(npm bin -g)`)

Comment: check the output of ```npm install -g node-gyp```. If you are running mcos, i d say that sudo could help. Otherwise let us know the OS.

Comment: @YanFoto Hi I did that and it said my appdata npm folder wasnt added to the PATH, so I added it, but any idea how to prevent this in the future / why it didnt work?\